# Between the kernel and the range of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a rectangular matrix $(m,n)$. Show that:

$$\ker (A^{T})\subset({\rm Im}(A))^{\perp}.$$

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward, no? Take ${\bf u} \in \ker(A^T)$. So $A^T{\bf u} = 0$ and from here ${\bf u}^TA = 0$. Now take $\bf v$ in ${\rm Im}(A)$ and let's check that ${\bf u}^T{\bf v} = 0.$ If ${\bf v} \in {\rm Im}(A)$, then ${\bf v} = A{\bf w}$ for some ${\bf w}$. Good, then: $${\bf u}^T{\bf v} = {\bf u}^T A {\bf w} = 0{\bf w} = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in \text{ker}(A^T)$, then $A^Tx = 0$. So for any $n \times 1$ column vector $y$,

$$\langle Ay,x\rangle = \langle y, A^Tx\rangle = \langle y, 0\rangle = 0.$$

This means $x \in (\text{Im}\, A)^\perp$.